# Why is variable overwritten in Ansible inventory configuration

Tags: ansible-inventory

## Setup

```
+---------+         +-----------+         +----------+
| Ansible |         | jump_host |         |  target  |
+---------+         +-----------+         +----------+
                  hproxy.shared.net    webserver.shared.net
```

With following Ansible inventory:

```
hosts:
    target:
        ansible_host: webserver.shared.net
vars:
    jump_host: hproxy.shared.net
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q {{jump_host}}"'
```

I'm playing this simple task on Ansible host:

```
- hosts: target
  name: Execute remote cmd
  command:
    cmd: ls -al
  register: output
```

## Problem

In Ansible console output, I get this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname https://hproxy.shared.net/: Name or service not known
```

Detailled error:

> <webserver.shared.net> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d11 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s-o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ProxyCommand=ssh -W %h:%p [https://hproxy.shared.net/'](https://hproxy.shared.net/%27) webserver.shared.net '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~user && sleep 0'"'"''
> ! <webserver.shared.net> (255, b'', b'OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\nssh: Could not resolve hostname https://hproxy.shared.net/: Name or service not known\r\nssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host\r\n')

But when I configure inventory this way, it's running perfectly:

```
[...]
vars:
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q hproxy.shared.net"'
```

(*hproxy.shared.net* instead of *{{jump_host}}*)

It's pretty clear, that the problem comes from adding https:// in front of hostname.

## Question

Is there a way to prevent Ansible adding this **https://** prefix in front of hostnames, when referencing them as Jinja variable ?

## Solution

I had 2 variables:

- in inventory group_vars/* (prio 6)`*`

  ```
   jump_host: 'https://henms-haproxy.sharedtcs.net/'
  ```
- in inventory file or script group vars (prio 2)`*`

  ```
   jump_host: henms-haproxy.sharedtcs.net
  ```

The first overwrite the second, because prio is higher.

`*` Ansible variable precedence: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable

*Tributes to Zeitounator*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that as pasted in your question, your inventory should fire errors since it does not respect a yaml inventory format convention on several points: `host` typo (=> `hosts`), host definitions are strings and not dictionaries... Moreover, you use `jump_host` as a variable identifier whereas it is only a host nickname in your inventory. Are you sure that var is not defined elsewhere?

Here are a few example to put you on track. Although "shortcuts" are allowed to avoid the `all` group at top level, I stuck to the [standard](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yaml_inventory.html) below.

Do you really need to define your jump host as a potential ansible target (i.e. are you really going to deploy on that host itself)? If no, you can modify your inventory as:

```yaml
---
all:
  vars:
    jump_host_address: hproxy.shared.net
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q {{ jump_host_address }}"'
  hosts:
    target:
      ansible_host: webserver.shared.net
```

If you want to keep the jump host in your inventory, chances are you will not use the proxy command to connect to it

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    jump_host:
      ansible_host: hproxy.shared.net
  children:
    targets_behind_jump:
      vars:
        ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q {{ hostvars.jump_host.ansible_host }}"'
      hosts:
        target:
          ansible_host: webserver.shared.net
```

Lastly, you should also ask yourself if you really need a nickname for your hosts. It's much easier IMO to manage the full fqdn names directly in the inventory (and have access to vars like `inventory_hostname` and `inventory_hostname_short`). Here are the two same examples using full names without and with jump host explicitly declared.

```yaml
---
all:
  vars:
    jump_host_address: hproxy.shared.net
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q {{ jump_host_address }}"'
  hosts:
    webserver.shared.net:
```

```yaml
---
all:
  vars:
    jump_host_name: hproxy.shared.net
  hosts:
    hproxy.shared.net:
  children:
    targets_behind_jump:
      vars:
        ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q {{ hostvars[jump_host_name].inventory_hostname }}"'
      hosts:
        webserver.shared.net:
```

Comment: I had indeed mistakes and you identified the **root cause**: Another variable was defined elsewhere, with same key and value "https://..."
My takeover are:
1. To separate _jump_host_ and _targets_behind_jump_ in 2 groups
2. To access FQDN names with hostvars.jump_host.ansible_host
Issue solved, many thanks ! But I should rename the title ?